# Formatting text for version control

Tags: regex, awk, sed

A lot of my documentation is written using LaTeX which, if properly formatted, is amenable to distributed workflow and version control. Specifically, I like to format text with one sentence per line.

My problem is that I have some legacy files to convert that do not follow this formatting policy and I would like to convert them in an automated way. I feel like this should be simple with some combination of `sed` and/or `awk`, but I am having some trouble.

I am trying to convert

```
This is some unformatted
text that does not have a sentence on one line.

This is a new unformatted paragraph
that does not follow the rule either.

This line \\ has a break in it.
```

to

```
This is some unformatted text that does not have a sentence on one line.

This is a new unformatted paragraph that does not follow the rule either.

This line \\
has a break in it.
```

The `sed`/`awk` that I have so far is as follows:

```
awk ' /^$/ { print "\n"; } /./ { printf("%s", $0); } END { print; } ' <filename> | sed -e $'s/\. /\.\\\n/g'
```

This gets me most of the way there, but I am having trouble getting the `\\` followed by a newline character to work properly.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solutions work and solve the problem, but could either of you explain what they are doing? @sjsam

Comment: @Ed Morton, please see above

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
$ cat text
This is some unformatted
text that does not have a sentence on one line.

This is a new unformatted paragraph
that does not follow the rule either.

This line \\ has a break in it.

This line too \\ contains break.
This is a normal line.
```

**Script**

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN{RS=".";}
 {$0=gensub(/([[:print:]?])\n/,"\\1 ","g");
 $0=gensub(/(\\\\) /,"\\1\n","g");
 printf "%s.",$0}
 END{printf "\n"}' text
```

**Output**

```
This is some unformatted text that does not have a sentence on one line.

This is a new unformatted paragraph that does not follow the rule either.

This line \\
has a break in it.

This line too \\
contains break.
This is a normal line .
```

**Note:** This assumes you have gnu-awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\\\\\\\\[[:space:]]*' -v OFS='\n' '{gsub(/\n/," "); $1=$1}1' file
This is some unformatted text that does not have a sentence on one line.

This is a new unformatted paragraph that does not follow the rule either.

This line
has a break in it.
```